# If I add a property to my Entity for an existing column in the table, do I need to use Migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

Using Code First EF6, the database table already includes a column that the Entity does not (I previously only accessed it as a navigation property). Now in order to hopefully speed up performance, I want to add the other, existing column so I can use in in my predicates. Do I need to worry about using migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You don't need to use migrations to create the column, obviously; however, EF may still see it as a mismatch between the model and the DB, because it bases its knowledge off of what's in the __MigrationHistory table. Try scaffolding the migration, and if it wants to add the column, call Update-Database -Script, then execute just the `INSERT INTO __MigrationHistory` part in order to convince EF that your DB is up to date.